# How to make a method change another method's return statement (boolean)

Tags: java

I want to write a method that changes the return statement of a different method. For example, I have 3 methods:

```
openCar
closeCar
isTheCarOpen:boolean
```

So if a user calls the method `openCar` and then calls the method `isTheCarOpen` it should return `true`.

```java
    public void openCar() {
        System.out.println("Car has been opened");
    }

    public void closeCar() {
        System.out.println("Car has been closed");

    }

    public boolean isTheCarOpen() {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't change the return statement. You change what the method returns. In your case, you want to have a boolean in the class representing the state of the door (let's call it `doorOpened`) and you set its value when you call the `openCar` and `closeCar` method.

```
class Car {
    private boolean doorOpened;

    public void openCar() {
        doorOpened = true;
        System.out.println("Car has been opened");
    }

    public void closeCar() {
        doorOpened = false;
        System.out.println("Car has been closed");
    }

    public boolean isTheCarOpen() {
        return doorOpened;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Federico! I tried to figure it out in many ways but failed.

Comment: You're welcome :) Whatever tutorial/book you're using to learn Java, toss it away. It's clearly not teaching you correctly. Or you skipped some chapters :P

Answer (score 1):

Simple: you add a **field** to the enclosing class, like:

```
public class Car {
  private boolean doorOpen = false;

  public boolean isDoorOpen() {
    return doorOpen;
  }
```

And now your different methods can all work with that!

In other words: instead of **hardcoding** the result of that method, you simply "point" it to some "internal state" of the surrounding class. In this case, you might also have a method like

```
  public void openDoors() {
    doorOpen = true;
  }
```

to enable the outside world to manipulate that state.

Answer (score 0):

Create the fields in your own class with the proper getters/setters:

```
 public class Car {
     private boolean carOpen;

     public void openCar() {
        System.out.println("Car has been opened");
        setCarOpen(true);
     }

     public void closeCar() {
        System.out.println("Car has been closed");
        setCarOpen(false);
     }

     public boolean isTheCarOpen() {
        return carOpen;
     }

     public void setCarOpen(boolean carOpen){
        this.carOpen = carOpen;
     }
 }
```

Comment: FYI, a `boolean` is false by default at declaration. No need to initialize it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean carOpen = false;
public void openCar() {
     carOpen = true;
}
public void closeCar() {
     carOpen = false;
}
public boolean isDoorOpen() {
     return carOpen;
}
```

Comment: Why is `carOpen` declared `static` if the methods are clearly not?